# Port 80 forwarding issue

Tags: networking, portforwarding

I have a very fun port forwarding issue.

I have been hosting a site off my local network for a couple years now.  Over the last 24 hours, it went down.  From my public ip and the dns I have assigned to it, I get a timeout and 404.  Port  and 443 are unblocked in the modem firewall.  The site is hosted on the local ip of 10.0.0.200.  Internally, if I browse that ip, I get the site.  If I browse my public ip, I don't.  Mind you, this has been working for years and as far as I know, there have been no updates to the modem.  I also tried hosting the site on another machine internally to make sure there were no security issues in the way or another other devices conflicting in the internal network.

Not totally sure what to do at this point except maybe replace the modem, that's the last thing I can think of.  Any help from the community would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the first two octets of the address on the WAN interface of your router? This is not necessarily your public IP address.

Comment: 73.192 I use google or whatismyip.com to determine my public ip.  the 10.0.0.1 router is the one from my isp, so its the one that gets the ip from the isp.  And I've tried sites that sniff port 80 and all say its open an listening, but browsing just wont hit.

Comment: I'm begining to think its an internal routing issue.  I just vpned into another network and was able to hit it from an incognito window....

Comment: So, you have a residential Internet connection, and that means your terms of service prohibit running services to the public Internet. What happened is that because of the IPv4 address shortage, your ISP changed its residential connections to use CGN in order to save its precious public addresses for businesses willing to pay for them. That breaks the port forwarding because you cannot configure the ISP NAT router to forward ports. The ISP does not care because you are violating the ToS.

Comment: That was also my first thought, however there is nothing in comcast's TOS about port 80, and they even host a page themselves showing you how to forward your ports with their gear.

Comment: That also would not explain why that site is available from outside the network, just not inside at that particular domain name

Comment: Port forwarding is not used on an internal network. It is a manual entry for the NAT table, and you do not use NAT internally.